# Parsing JSON in SAS

Tags: json, sas

Does anyone know how to convert the following JSON to table format in SAS? Appreciate in advance any help!

**JSON**

```
{
  "totalCount": 2,
  "facets": {},
  "content": [
    [
      {
        "name": "customer_ID",
        "value": "1"
      },
      {
        "name": "customer_name",
        "value": "John"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "name": "customer_ID",
        "value": "2"
      },
      {
        "name": "customer_name",
        "value": "Jennifer"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

**Desired Output**

| customer_ID | customer_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Jennifer |

**Steps I've Taken**

1- Call API

```
filename request "C:\path.request.txt";
filename response "C:\path.response.json";    
filename status "C:\path.status.json";     
proc http
url="http://httpbin.org/get"
method="POST"
in=request
out=response
headerout=status;
run;
```

2- I have the following JSON MAP file save:

```
{
  "DATASETS": [
    {
      "DSNAME": "customers",
      "TABLEPATH": "/root/content",
      "VARIABLES": [
        {
          "NAME": "name",
          "TYPE": "CHARACTER",
          "PATH": "/root/content/name"
        },
        {
          "NAME": "value",
          "TYPE": "CHARACTER",
          "PATH": "/root/content/value"
        }
        
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

3- I use the above JSON Map file as follow:

```
filename jmap "C:\path.jmap.map"; 
libname cust json map=jmap access=readonly;
proc copy inlib=cust outlib=work;
run;
```

4- This generates a table like this, which is not what I need:

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| customer_id | 1 |
| customer_value | John |
| customer_id | 2 |
| customer_value | Jennifer |

Comment: Have you tried a JSON libname approach? https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2016/12/02/json-libname-engine-sas/

Comment: I tried that approach and it works well when the JSON is structured differently, but I have not been able to get it to work with the JSON above. I've tried json map, scan function, etc..nothing has worked for me and I've spent days on this :-(

Comment: @CooperM What have you tried with `libname JSON`?  It seems like it gets pretty close to me - you just need a transpose. Show your work - then we can help fix it.

Comment: Hi, I added more details. Thanks in advance for your time and any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From where you are, you have a very trivial step to convert to what you want - `PROC TRANSPOSE`.

```
filename test "h:\temp\test.json";

libname test json;

data pre_trans;
  set test.content;
  if name='customer_ID' then row+1;
run;

proc transpose data=pre_trans out=want;
  by row;
  id name;
  var value;
run;
```

You could also do this directly in the data step; there are advantages to going either way.

```
data want;
  set test.content;
  retain customer_ID customer_name;
  if name='customer_ID' then customer_ID=input(value,best.);
  else if name='customer_name' then do;
    customer_name = value;
    output;
 end;
run;
```

This data step works okay for the example above - the `proc transpose` works better for more complex examples, as you only have to hardcode the one value.

I suspect you could do this more directly with a proper JSON map, but I don't usually do this sort of thing that way - it's easier for me to just get it into a dataset and then work with it from there.

In this case, SAS is getting tripped up by the double arrays with no content before the second array - if there was some (any) content there, it would parse more naturally.  Since there's nothing for SAS to really judge what you want to do with that Content array, it just lets you do whatever you want with it - which is easy enough.

Comment: Joe - The transpose solution worked perfectly! Thank you so much! I've spent so much time on this and so i really appreciate your help!